# FTP with AWS elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ftp, sftp

I am quite newbie and trying to figure out how to configure sftp or ftp with aws elastic beanstalk. I am using filezila, and is wondering where I could grab the proper credentials to set it up.

Thanks

Comment: You can connect ec2 created by elasticbean via your public ip/DNS securitykey.pem available in aws

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't. Elastic beanstalk is not designed for ftp. The key idea behind elastic beanstalk is that it can pull out an instance at anytime and replace it with another. If you use ftp, you'll lose all your work.

If you really want ftp, just use a raw ec2 server.

Comment: Is there a workaround to connect.

( https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=508895) 

If put directly on EC2, lose data too?

Comment: @Claudionor I am confused as to what your asking. Could you rephrase your comment?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.
I was looking for a solution to upload the files via FTP and found an answer in the forum Amazon. But, the first connection to EC2, showed the message:

"
This EC2 instance is managed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Changes made via SSH
WILL BE LOST if the instance is replaced by auto-scaling. For more information
on customizing your Elastic Beanstalk environment, see our documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

"

Comment: That's correct. As my answer states, you can loose your work. So if you want to use ftp, just do EC2 and don't use Elastic Beanstalk.